# Angular 2: check if shift key is down when an element is clicked

Tags: angular

In an Angular 2 app, i want the click event to trigger something different when *the shift key is being held down*. how to achieve this?

html is below:

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="#obj of available" (click)="toggleSelected(obj)"></div>
```

and i want to do something like this:

```
  toggleSelected(obj) {
    if(shift is pressed) {
      do this
    } else {
      do that
    }
  }
```

so how can i detect if shift key is pressed? thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In the `(click)` binding, pass the `$event` object to the `toggleSelected` method:

```html
<div class="item" *ngFor="#obj of available" (click)="toggleSelected(obj, $event)"></div>
```

In the `toggleSelected` method, check whether the event's `shiftKey` property is `true`:

```js
toggleSelected(obj, event) {
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    // do this
  } else {
    // do that
  }
}
```

Comment: where should i capture the `$event`? it says undefined.

Comment: @dragon_cat: Make sure you pass `$event` as the second argument in the `(click)` binding, and that you add `event` as a parameter to `toggleSelected`.

Comment: great answer. Just for completeness: I've added an answer which mentions the types of the parameters as well. Which is useful if you use codecompletion (e.g. in visual studio code).

Answer (score 9):

Your question may refer to multi-select option for records of a table.

In that case you could store the selected objects in a set.

```
public selectedRowSet: Set<MyObject> = new Set();
```

Each time a record is selected, you use the following method to add them to a set.

```
public setSelectedRow(obj: MyObject, event: MouseEvent) {
  if(!event.shiftKey) {
    selectedRowSet.clear();
  }
  selectedRowSet.add(obj);
}
```

Then you probably want to add conditional formatting.

```
public isRowSelected(obj: MyObject): boolean
{
  return selectedRowSet.has(obj);
}
```

In your view use:

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of myObjectCollection" 
    [class.someCssClass]="isRowSelected(obj)" 
    (click)="setSelectedRow(obj, $event);">
...
</tr>
```

---

## REVIEW

Here are some additional tweaks, which may be useful:

- you can choose to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> (for apple)
- records can also be deselected if this key is pressed.

I hope this is useful for somebody.

```
public setSelectedRow(bo: Bo, event: MouseEvent) {
  // support shift, control and the command key.
  const add = event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
  if (!add) {
    this.selectedRowSet.clear();
    this.selectedRowSet.add(bo);
    return;
  }

  // toggle selected record
  if (this.selectedRowSet.has(bo)) {
    this.selectedRowSet.delete(bo);
  }
  else {
    this.selectedRowSet.add(bo);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same for `command` on mac, 
`const add = event.keyCode === 91 || event.shiftKey;` but it does not work,
by any chance do you know why?

Comment: @JSON according to the mozilla documentation it should be `event.metaKey` ( i.e. `const add = event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey`) source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/metaKey

Comment: I included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is that [keyboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey) event has this built in.

```
<input (keydown)="onKey($event)"` ...
```

For instance focus inside a field, hold shift and then another key.

The keyboard event contains `shiftKey: boolean`

Answer (score -1):

Use `keypress`

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="#obj of available" (keypress)="eventHandler($event)"></div>

eventHandler(event) {
   console.log(event, event.keyCode, event.keyIdentifier);
}
```