# Angular 6 routerLink on a new tab

Tags: angular

I'm trying to open a routerlink on a new tab instead of on the current page but regular html attributes like target _blank are not working.

```
<span routerLink="/custompage/{{city.id}}"  class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">open</span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Routing run in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355830/angular-2-routing-run-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here's an alternate way of doing within a component.

```
openCityInNewWindow(city) {
  // Converts the route into a string that can be used 
  // with the window.open() function
  const url = this.router.serializeUrl(
    this.router.createUrlTree([`/custompage/${city.id}`])
  );

  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Html will look something like

```
<ul *ngFor="let city of cities">
  <li (click)="openCityInNewWindow(city.id)">{{city.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Rwin +1 Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: One of the disadvantages with this solution is not being able to use CTRL + CLICK. A real UX lack

Comment: @LYES-CHIOUKH unless you add this solution as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45884676/2901207

Comment: Is work for me I added # window.open("#" + url.toString(), '_blank'), thanks. and in my case I didn't use serializeUrl.

Comment: Click on an <li> element is not semantic, so it would not work as expected and will not be accessible. Please use semantic HTML.

Comment: <li (click)="openCityInNewWindow(city.id)">{{city.name}}</li> should be avoided if you includes accessibility. The click event on the <li> is not natural. click is done on buttons. You could add role="button" to fix it. Personally i avoid navigating on any click event because if you get used to it you will not be able to use rightclick navigationstuff in the browser

Answer (score 40):

you can add target="_blank" to your link

it works for me:

```
 <a routerLink="/News" routerLinkActive="active" target="_blank" rel="bookmark"></a>
```

Comment: Using href instead of routerLink worked for me. With routerLink I got error on target and rel.

Answer (score 26):

There is a [newer way of opening new tabs using routerLink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61661996/10959940), but in my opinion, this is still a simpler option, as both methods still require to make use of `window.open()`.

On your component.ts,

```
openNewTab(url) {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

or this on your component.html

```
<a href="www.domain.com/custompage/{{city.id}}" target="_blank">
```

Another valid alternative is to write your own custom directives. Check it out over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355830/angular-2-routing-run-in-new-tab), that person has already written a sample implementation of it.

Comment: A note about `window.open()`: it will not always work on all browsers. Not allowed in Safari iOS unless placed in an `onClick` attribute.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the exact same issue and i think i've found the best of both worlds.

Change your DIV, SPAN into A tags. Add the href link but keep the routerLink.

```
<a routerLink="/custompage/{{city.id}}"  href="/custompage/{{city.id}}" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">open</a>
```

How it should work now :

- Left click -> go to corresponding route / page without a new reload ;
- Right click -> Open in new tab / window options and would naturally load a new page when using this navigation

Answer (score 12):

I find the solution and fixed this as below

```html
 <a [routerLink]="['/unauth/profile',data.userId]" target="_blank" class="FullViewLink">FullView<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

You can targe="_blank" in routerLink. It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a button, simply put the button inside the a tag

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Start Over</button>
</a>
```