# Right click open in new tab is not available on routerlink withhin a div tag

Tags: html, angular, router, routerlink

I have a `div` element or `tr` element and there is a router link on it.

Since it isnt an `a` tag, there is no option for right-clicking and "open in new tab" or strg + click for opening in new tab.

But i want to achieve this function, so if the user wants to open the link in new tab, he could do it like described. I can't change my tr into an a tag.

Is there any possiblity to get this functionality "open in new tab" without an `a` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 routerLink on a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483451/angular-6-routerlink-on-a-new-tab)

Comment: No, i dont want, that it opens always in a tab. There should be the option with right click to open it on a new tab

Answer (score 3):

href reload the page no need to use in SPA.

It only works on anchor tag to show menus when right-click use. like "open in new tab"

It can be used on a button.

you can use the code below for your purpose.

default open in new tab = target="_blank"

```
<a target="_blank" [routerLink]="'/edit/'+prop.id"> 

<a [routerLink]="'/edit/'+prop.id">
```

Answer (score 0):

No, only links have the `href` attribute.

From there, two options :

- Create a link on the fly
- append a link as the direct child of your element

Create a link on the fly :

```html
<tr (click)="inNewTab()">
```

```js
inNewTab() {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = '';
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.click();
  link.remove();
}
```

Use a link as the direct element :

```html
<tr>
  <a href="" target="_blank">...</a>
</tr>
```

```css
tr > a[target="_blank"] {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: we can use anchor tag without href. href reload the site so we need the best solution which I provide.