# Can Angular 2 routes with params, be opened in new tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, navigation

Currently I have angular app with routing. The routes work fine when accessed from the app, but when I try to copy and paste certain link in a new tab, I get that the module could not be loaded. example `http://localhost:4200/updates` works fine both opened in the application and in new tab,
yet `http://localhost:4200/updates/repositories/Test/units` (Test is parameter which is passed from the calling component)this url works only in the app, when pasted in a new tab the error that I am seeing is:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' scripts.91672879d55182c59502.js:1`

`Loading module from “http://localhost:4200/updates/repositories/sumDev/main-es2017.233f600c1169f07fe825.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

`units Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost:4200/updates/repositories/sumDev/main-es2017.233f600c1169f07fe825.js”.`

this is my dependency setup:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.14",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@delite/dlt-icons": "^1.1.5",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "keycloak-angular": "^8.2.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^13.0.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-http-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },



 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.14",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.8"
  }
```

this is the routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: "installer",
                pathMatch: "full"

            },{
                path: 'updates',
                component: UpdateRepositoryComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'repositories/:name/units',
                        component: UnitsComponent,
                    }
                ]
            }]
    }]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And this is how I navigate `this.router.navigate([this.router.url +` /repositories/${name}/units`]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is the nature of Client Site Rendering - CSR, it only works when you navigate by code.

In short, entering url directly will trigger a Server request, well, you don't have a server to handle that request so error happens. More about this could be found on gooogle with CSR keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this by using HashLocationStrategy. This adds # infront of the url and helped with the routing. You can find full explanation and example [here](https://medium.com/@dao.houssene/angular-the-hash-trap-b2d415c2c241)

Comment: Yes, this should work. I forgot to mention it. Thanks for bring it up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

or check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483451/angular-6-routerlink-on-a-new-tab)

Comment: this does not load the component

Comment: I want for example to start the app, directly paste the url and see the result. This does not happen. When I go to home page and from there navigate to the url, it works fine